# Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode (referenced from: com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, minify

I updated my android studio to **"Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1"** now I have problems in some projects:

> Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in **"Location Address"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roU0g.png)

and the missing classes are:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode (referenced from: com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)\r\nMissing class comMissing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode (referenced from: com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)

Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode (referenced from: com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)

Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe (referenced from: com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)
```

My Gradle.build file:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_id"
        minSdk 20
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'app_id'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    //admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.11.0.1'
    //firebase
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    // Add the dependency for the Analytics library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'
}
```

Please help me in this problem.

Answer (score 22):

I have solved this problem by adding the following dependencies

`implementation 'com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.18.0'`

Hope, it will help.

Comment: It's working, it is really helpful for me.

Comment: @Rafiqullah Taibzada Ok, good to hear that. Will you please mark it as accepted answer then?

Comment: it's not a solution, there should be just some proguard rules...

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:
try to create release then go to `yourproject\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt`.

check the `missing_rules.txt` and there will be some rules generated by the gradle itself, just copy and include it in the proguard rules pro.

Solution 2:
Simply adding this

```
implementation 'com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.18.0'
```

Hope this helps